# Moving to ActiveDirectory from indidivual profiles and keeping all settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, active-directory, user-profiles

Currently we have about 25-30 systems and I am considering going to Active Directory for easier management and pushing of updates. However, playing around with Windows I have learned that it can and is a real pain working with profile and keeping everything the same.

Is it possible to move everyone into an AD Profile and keep all their settings/gui/applications the same without having to do reinstall and rebuild their profiles?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to (running as an admin) launch the Windows Easy Transfer program. It is meant for migrating to a new computer, but you can choose to export only your profile.

Once you export it to a file on a local disk, launch it again, this time select "this is my new computer", click advanced and it will let you map from one profile to another and click transfer.

This will import everything except user specific registry data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be a third party application:

[User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html)

> User Profile Wizard is a scalable, enterprise grade, workstation
>   migration tool that can automatically migrate workstations to a new
>   domain from an existing Windows network, from a Novell NDS network or
>   join standalone computers to a domain for the first time – and
>   maintain user profile data and settings.

Basic version is FREE.